# Reconnect with popup window after reload

Tags: javascript, window

I have music player, that consists of two parts. First, the main page is page, where you can pick songs from database, add them to playlist,... The other window is player itself (displays sound controls, current playlist, album cover,...). Player window is opened using window.open in main window.

I want to leave player window open, even when you close the main window, so you can do other things and have the music still playing and controllable.

My problem is, after reopening the main page, is there a way to connect to player window again? Or at least, close it and reopen it?

I couldn't find any way to do this. If it isn't possible, I had and idea, that main page could communicate with player through LocalStorage (both sides would be periodically checking if there is anything new). Is there any better method?

Answer (score 0):

[Intercom](https://github.com/diy/intercom.js) is a library that uses local storage to implement broadcast messaging between windows.

Local storage fires an event (`onstorage`) when data changes, so no polling is necessary.  Intercom allows *all* pages on a domain to communicate, regardless of how they were opened.